# Error message in VS when building ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

> Error 1   An error occurred loading a
>   configuration file: Failed to start
>   monitoring changes to
>   '\server1\d$\Software
>   Development\xxx\newVersion'
>   because the network BIOS command limit
>   has been reached. For more information
>   on this error, please refer to
>   Microsoft knowledge base article
>   810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP
>   Platform. \server1\d$\Software
>   Development\xxx\newVersion\Web.config 1

The knowledge base article is:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886/en-us

It tells me to regedit and increase some values.  The key doesn't even exist.  But this site was working fine about 5 minutes ago, I just added a few lines of code which still don't work!  This error came out of nowhere!

The webserver only has 50mb free space, is this going to cause this?

Any help appreciated I'm stumped.

**Edit: The web config file**

The web.config file seemed to have 1/2 missing so I replaced it wit a default one.  I get the same error.

I noticed I get a bunch of warnings as well when trying to rebuild:

```
Message 1   Could not find schema information for the element 'compilers'.  \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 91  10  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 2   Could not find schema information for the element 'compiler'.   \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 92  14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 3   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'language'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 92  23  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 4   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'extension'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 92  47  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 5   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'warningLevel'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 92  63  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 6   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 93  23  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 7   Could not find schema information for the element 'providerOption'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 94  18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 8   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 94  33  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 9   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 94  56  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 10  Could not find schema information for the element 'providerOption'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 95  18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 11  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 95  33  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 12  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 95  52  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 13  Could not find schema information for the element 'compiler'.   \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 97  14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 14  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'language'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 97  23  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 15  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'extension'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 97  62  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 16  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'warningLevel'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 97  78  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 17  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 98  23  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 18  Could not find schema information for the element 'providerOption'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 99  18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 19  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 99  33  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 20  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 99  56  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 21  Could not find schema information for the element 'providerOption'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 100 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 22  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 100 33  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 23  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 100 52  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 24  Could not find schema information for the element 'providerOption'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 101 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 25  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 101 33  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 26  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 101 52  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 27  Could not find schema information for the element 'validation'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 111 10  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 28  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'validateIntegratedModeConfiguration'.  \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 111 21  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 29  Could not find schema information for the element 'modules'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 112 10  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 30  Could not find schema information for the element 'remove'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 113 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 31  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 113 21  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 32  Could not find schema information for the element 'add'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 114 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 33  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 114 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 34  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'preCondition'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 114 38  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 35  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 114 68  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 36  Could not find schema information for the element 'handlers'.   \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 116 10  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 37  Could not find schema information for the element 'remove'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 117 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 38  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 117 21  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 39  Could not find schema information for the element 'remove'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 118 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 40  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 118 21  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 41  Could not find schema information for the element 'remove'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 119 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 42  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 119 21  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 43  Could not find schema information for the element 'remove'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 120 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 44  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 120 21  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 45  Could not find schema information for the element 'add'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 121 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 46  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 121 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 47  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'verb'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 121 46  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 48  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'path'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 121 55  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 49  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'preCondition'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 121 69  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 50  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 122 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 51  Could not find schema information for the element 'add'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 123 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 52  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 123 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 53  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'verb'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 123 57  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 54  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'path'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 123 66  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 55  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'preCondition'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 123 90  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 56  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 124 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 57  Could not find schema information for the element 'add'.    \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 125 14  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 58  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 125 18  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 59  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'preCondition'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 125 40  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 60  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'verb'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 125 70  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 61  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'path'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 125 86  \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Message 62  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 125 112 \\server1\d$\...\newVersion\
Error   63  An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion' because the network BIOS command limit has been reached. For more information on this error, please refer to Microsoft knowledge base article 810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform. \\server1\d$\Software Development\xxx\newVersion\web.config 1
```

**Re-edit**

Not a web.config problem apparently, if I delete it I get the same error

Comment: What system are you running on?

Comment: @TToni Windows Server 2003 with IIS6.  I can't reset the server today though which is a shame.

Comment: Restarted VS and it's fixed it.  Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst restarting VS has fixed the problem - the biggest issue you have is that the site is hosted on a network share.

Asp.Net is setting up file watchers on the application's directory in order to provide the automatic-tear-down functionality for the AppDomain if critical files change.

On earlier versions of windows this feature either doesn't work across a network share (but Asp.Net doesn't fail), or if it does it's extremely limited.  I think in this case an existing watcher is being thought to have been dropped and another one is being recreated again (probably by the OS), eventually exhausting system resources as duplicate watchers are being created again and again.

This is better supported on Win 2008+ (client and server required) as there is deeper integration of network file systems and watchers to the OS.

However, I would highly recommend that, especially during development, websites running on a local IIS are also run from the local file system.